# How can i get return data from listener?

Tags: swing

I am testing some code and facing some problem that in using listener. I want String return data from mouseListener. when some label is clicked, mouseListener return that label's data like that. Pls Help!......

Edit ...I have referenced some code from this site at autoComplete category. And I test to use this by creating object for each textfield (e.g ....first autoComplete object for first textfield and second autoComplete object for second textfield ,etc..). But when I created second object, the first one was unresponse. Here is my code link .....
http://www.mediafire.com/download/op9mfpkyughrq3d/AutoCompleteImp.rar

Comment: 1) Listeners methods have `void` return type , you can't return values from them, but you can manage that values inside listener. 2) What do you try to do, show your attempts.

Comment: Listener have void types, so you can add some function and call it in listener that return string types. and define that function outside that listener.